# How can I restore login in GDM3 screen? It disappeared after upgrade from Debia 8 to 9, thus GDM3 doesn't starts anymore!

Tags: debian, pam, gdm3

During an upgrade of Debian 8 to 9 I was asked about PAM Modules package installation.

How i didn't knew the correct answer, I choosed option 1. Unix Authentication.

Now the GDM3 doesn't starts anymore and my journalctl reads the following, repeatedly:

`May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm3[809]: Unable to kill session worker process
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm-launch-environment][5948]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user Debian-gdm by (uid=0)
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[5951]: Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1'
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[5951]: Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session[5951]: Unable to register display with display manager
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm-launch-environment][5948]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user Debian-gdm
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm3[809]: Child process -5951 was already dead.
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm3[809]: Child process 5948 was already dead.
May 06 08:32:03 jesacer gdm3[809]: Unable to kill session worker process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed, in Aptitude, to reinstall all packages with PAM name on it.

That way, when asked which modules should be installed, choosed all of them: 1 2 3 4, instead of only 1.

Then executed `dpkg-reconfigure gdm3` to reconfigure GDM3.

Now it seems to be all right.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed the issue using

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 gnome-shell
$ restart
```

I tried installing plasma-kde desktop environment which did not install correctly. I removed plasma-desktop and problem started. Though I wasn't getting the black screen, instead a login prompt.